# AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I was not able to find any examples of passing script arguments to a sql activity in pipeline. Tried some options like passing arguments directly and using them via $1 but nothing seems to be working. If any one has got it working, would be good see a example of that, what format arguments should be and how to access them in the sql

Comment: can you please share your pipelineid. I can take a look at your usecase. $1, $2 should work when you are passing scriptArguments.

Comment: if u can let me know the format of script arguments that we need to give, that would actually help. I don't have a pipeline created right now.

Answer (score 0):

you can define parameters and use them in script arguments.

reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-custom-templates.html

we also have various samples in github that you can check out: https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples